# R Shiny not uploading

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

So i recently created a basic app to learn more about Shiny.

The app works when I try it locally (Global.R) but when I separate it into ui.R and server.R and upload it to the server, i keep on getting an error:

> Warning: Error in sort: object 'mydata' not found

Server Code

```
#import libraries
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
mydata <- read.csv("course-proj-data.csv", header = T, sep = ";")
attach(mydata)
server = function(input, output, session){

  filterData <- reactive({
    mydata[which(mydata$Team == input$team),]
  })
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(filterData(), selection = "single", rownames = F)
  })

}
```

UI Code

```
#User Interface
ui = navbarPage(theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("cerulean"), title = ("Fifa World Cup 2018"),
                tabPanel(
                  "Statistics by country",
                  wellPanel(
                    selectInput("team", label = h3("Select Country"), 
                                choices = sort(mydata$Team), 
                                selected = 1),

                    hr(),
                    fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

                  ),
                  DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
                )
)
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is the file location correct? Can you try with absolute path first?

Comment: its all in one folder / directory. I followed the Shiny documentation when referring to the data so i put it in that specific format.

Comment: Like I said, try with absolute path first to figure whether that's the problem or not. After that you can play with `setwd()` to make sure you dont use absolute values

Comment: can you give an example of an absolute path

Comment: instead of `course-proj-data.csv`, put in the full path - something like `C:/Users/123/course-proj-data.csv`

Comment: As a debug step, you could print a call to `list.files()` and `getwd()` before the `read.csv()`. I imagine the csv wont be shown, what is shown might help though.

Comment: @MichaelBird Its shown in the list.files(). It also shows the server.R, ui.R and rsconnect.

Comment: The issue is that you reference `mydata` in the `ui` variable which is being evaluated before `server.R`. Try moving the `read.csv` command into `global.R`

Comment: Can you explain how to move it from the UI to the global, I'm still learning Shiny.

Comment: create a file called `global.R` in the same directory as your `ui.R` and `server.R` and move the call to `read.csv()` from the `server.R` file to the `global.R` file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like you, in the end I just saved the input data as an .RData file that I loaded before everything else in the Server code.

```
# load packages
library(shiny)

load("loaddata.RData")

server <- function(input, output) {
....
```